# How to query the maximum number for each group in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to have the maxim date for each group in a separate column:

This is my data:

```
Customer  Date   

A          5/6/2017
A          11/7/2017
B          5/7/2017
A          9/7/2017
B          4/5/2017
```

And this will be my ideal output:

```
Customer   Date             MAX    

A          5/6/2017       11/7/2017
A          11/7/2017      11/7/2017   
B          5/7/2017       5/7/2017
A          9/7/2017       11/7/2017
B          4/5/2017       5/7/2017
```

That caluclate the maximum date for each group (in this example Group A and Group B) and return the value.

I tried this query

```
={"MAX";arrayformula (QUERY( A:B, "Select MAX(B) group by (A)"))}
```

But It doesn't give me what I'm looking for. Any tip is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with copying a formula down the column, then

```
=max(filter(B:B, A:A=A2))
```

will do the job (the entry of C2 shown).

I can't think of a way to produce the desired result with arrayformula, but here is a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to that effect: it can be used like `=groupmax(A2:B100)`

```
function groupmax(data) {
  var max = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (max[data[i][0]] == undefined || max[data[i][0]] < data[i][1]) {
      max[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
    }
  }
  return data.map(function(r) {
    return [max[r[0]]];       // see below
  });
}
```

If you want the function to also return the original data, change the line with the comment to

```
    return [r[0], r[1], max[r[0]]];
```

Comment: Thanks @ALex. it looks good but I never used Google Scripts. Can you please guide me a little bit. If I use `=groupmax(A2:B100)` how do I refer to this instead of `data.length`?

Comment: I linked a page that explains custom functions step by step. The code goes in the script editor. After that, the function is used like any spreadsheet function. It returns a column of values.